# How to query only custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, caml-query, csom

Is it posible to query only custom list? In SharePoint you can add different type of list i.e tasks, contacts etc. I want to retrieve all items that the current user has created only if the items are in custom lists. And it should retreive from multiple list not only from just 1 list.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into the Generic List type. That's the one being used for Custom lists.

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you please elaborate your answer please or show something I can start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158168/how-to-get-all-the-list-and-the-items-that-are-in-the-lists#answer-158178). It query only custom lists by checking list base template.

Comment: @sunreuz Please up vote the answer if you have accepted it as a solution. It motivates :)