# How to get all the list and the items that are in the lists?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, caml-query

Is it possible to retreive all the items from different list in SharePoint? I know how to retreive list items from 1 list but not multiple lists.

```
var mylist = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can look though all lists and get list items one by one.

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();

clientContext.load(lists);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var enumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    var listItemsCollection = [];

    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = enumerator.get_current();

        // Add your own truth test here or remove it if you want to query all lists
        if (list.get_baseTemplate() === 100) {
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            var listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

            listItemsCollection.push(listItems);
            clientContext.load(listItems);
        }
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // Now you can access the array of SP.ListItemCollection
        for (var i = 0, length = listItemsCollection.length; i < length; i++) {
            var items = listItemsCollection[i];
            var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var listItem = enumerator.get_current();

                console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
            }
        }
    }, function (sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}, function (sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Xiaodan! Do you know how to query only items that the current user has created? I tried with something like this `var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            var textCAML = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
            camlQuery.set_viewXml(textCAML);`

Comment: @Sunreuz Please try this: `var textCAML = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Author\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>your user</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';` You didn't specify the value of Author field.

Answer (score -1):

use sharepoint rest api

/_api/web/lists

/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx

Comment: your solution will get items from a particular list only not all lists as per question.